# Place Picker Deprecated

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I received an email today regarding the Google Place Picker.

"The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. You must install the compatibility library to continue using the Place Picker during the deprecation period. Once the deprecation period has ended, the Place Picker will no longer be available for use (including the version in the compatibility library)."

They just mentioned that it will no longer work eventually but they did not specify the replacement to it. So what will developers now use to enable our users to pick places?

Comment: It looks like there is no replacement for Place Picker in new version of SDK. At least Google doesn't mention any replacement in migration guide: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration. I guess we should implement it from the scratch.

Comment: It is actually a pity! the Placepicker has the map, the selection button, a place image and autoplacecomplete in one package ready for use! I hope they make something similar if not its a ton of work to make from scratch

Comment: Google is really seeking for revenue. They deprecated the PlacePicker because of the Places API new billing model. The PlacePicker gives for us many free NearbySearch() queries that now costs US$ 0.04 each. It also gives a free photo when you pick the place that now costs US$ 0.007 per photo. So, if you want a Place Picker, you should implement it and pay accordingly.

Comment: Google is tracking the interest in having a Place Picker widget here: (Android) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760. Please fill the linked form with your use case and needs if you are interested.

Comment: Does someone know a 100% library of a place picker, when I only want to select a position on the map? Without search and POIs?

Answer (score 3):

So I made a free version of Place Picker. It's not as feature rich but is free. It uses geocoder to fetch the address and coordinates of a place. Will be adding more features like optional Autocomplete Widget (Its not free though) in the next few days. Check it put here:

https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker

Comment: Any alternative for iOS ?

Comment: Java Version of this

Answer (score 1):

My original answer with **15 upvotes** was deleted without reason... I'm reposting it here..

---

As my app heavily depends on the Place Picker, I decided to create a new one based on Google's Place Picker.

https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker

Take a look at the key difference [here](https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker#a-key-difference)